# How can I alter the list of available layouts in the Panels IPE?

Tags: 8, plugins

I'm trying to hide or remove several layouts from the layout selectors, so that users can only select from an approved list. I can do this successfully with `hook_form_alter()` code, but the Panels IPE isn't using a form for its layout selection tray. It seems the best method would be to use LayoutPluginManagerInterface somehow, so that *any* function that displays a list of available layouts will have the same list available, but so far I haven't figured it out. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to curate the Panels IPE more to my liking, and so far, it seems like overriding the controller is a decent way to go.

Say you're wanting to do this in my_example module:

- Inside your custom module, create src/Controller/CustomPanelsIPEController.php. We want to extend from panels_ipe/src/Controller/PanelsIPEPageController.php into this file, and change the namespace declaration and change the class name to match:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

  use Drupal\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController;

  /**
   * Contains all JSON endpoints required for Panels IPE + Page Manager.
   */
  class MyModuleIPEController extends PanelsIPEPageController {
  ...
  ```
- Now, we need to have our routing subscriber tune in to panels IPE being called, and re-route it to our new method. Create src/Routing/MyExampleRoutingSubscriber.php, and add the following:

  ```
  namespace Drupal\my_example\Routing;

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  /**
   * Listens to the dynamic route events.
   */
  class MyExampleRoutingSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('panels_ipe.block_plugins')) {
        $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_example\Controller\MyModuleIPEController:getBlockPlugins');
      }
    }
  }
  ```

So now what will happen is our Panels IPE is now calling our method.

So now, we can do some more precise altering. For a simple example, when it comes to creating blocks, let's say we wanted to only give users a single module called 'awesome_blocks' for their choices when creating content.

```
public function getBlockPluginsData($panels_storage_type, $panels_storage_id) {
   $panels_display = $this->loadPanelsDisplay($panels_storage_type, 
   $panels_storage_id);

   // Get block plugin definitions from the server.
   $definitions = $this->blockManager->getDefinitionsForContexts($panels_display->getContexts());

   // Assemble our relevant data.
   $blocks = [];
   foreach ($definitions as $plugin_id => $definition) {
     if ($definition['provider'] == "awesome_blocks") { // Added this logic
     ...
```

In this simple example, I've altered the logic to ONLY show blocks from the awesome_blocks module. Now of curse, I was altering the blocks, and you were asking about the layouts. The layouts can be altered the same way! Inside of the `getLayoutsData()` function that is in this same class, you could implement custom logic. To alter the layouts in the same way, we could add another function inside our custom Routing controller, inside the alterRoutes() method:

```
    if ($route = $collection->get('panels_ipe.layouts')) {
        $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_example\Controller\MyModuleIPEController:getLayouts');
    }
```

Now, just implement custom logic in the getLayouts method:

```
public function getLayoutsData($panels_storage_type, $panels_storage_id) {
    $panels_display = $this->loadPanelsDisplay($panels_storage_type, $panels_storage_id);

    // Get the current layout.
    $current_layout_id = $panels_display->getLayout()->getPluginId();

    // Get a list of all available layouts.
    $layouts = $this->layoutPluginManager->getDefinitions();
    $base_path = base_path();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($layouts as $id => $layout) {
        if ($layout['provider'] == 'my_layout_module') { // Added logic check here
        ...
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi,
I added the controller and routing as you mentioned here. But, Drupal is not detecting this Controller and Routing. I didn't even get any debugging errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that with the latest versions (8.3 +) you can simply unset the ones you aren't using with (must be in a module, doesn't work in (our) theme):

function [my_module_name]_layout_alter(&$definitions) {
  // Disable default layouts.
  unset($definitions['layout_onecol']);
  unset($definitions['layout_twocol']);
  unset($definitions['layout_twocol_bricks']);
  unset($definitions['layout_threecol_25_50_25']);
  unset($definitions['layout_threecol_33_34_33']);
}
(This will error on any layout that you are currently using (hint: one-column is default).
Referenced from here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/panels/issues/2812999

Then, all you have to do is provide layouts of your own using the Drupal Core Layout Discovery (formerly Layouts plugin):
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/layout-api/how-to-register-layouts#simplest-case

Using Category names, you can make the UI just how it is provided, except it will use your own custom layouts.